# How to create a new file and copy content of existing file into newly created file python

Tags: python

I have a python function here that takes in 2 params, old_file is the name of the file that contains the content that I want to copy over to the new file and the new_file is the name for the file I want to create. Right now my code looks like this and it would throw an error which is a type error that says "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper". Is there a more efficient way to do it?. In addition when I point at with open(file, "r+") as f2: I get this warning

Note. this works if the file is already pre-made but not when i make it in the function

```
def copy_In(old_file, new_file):

    file = open(new_file, "w")

    with open(file, "r+") as f2:
        for x in range(10):
            f2.readline()
        pos = f2.tell()
        f2_remainder = f2.read()
        f2.seek(pos)
        with open(old_file, "r") as f1:
            for line in f1:
                f2.write(line)
        f2.write(f2_remainder)
```

[image: error]

Comment: The *shutil* module will be your saviour

Comment: Post the full traceback message so we can easily see the failing line.

Comment: why do you double open new file?

Comment: I got the second open from another source, and it is suppose to copy and write the file to the new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it like:

```py
def copy_file(old_fname, new_fname):
    with open(old_fname, "rt") as old_fobj, open(new_fname, "wt") as new_fobj:
        new_fobj.write(old_fobj.read())
```

we are opening first file in read mode and second in write mode and reading the entire content of first file and writing it in second file.